# Is this the correct syntax to send a GET request URL?

Tags: javascript, ajax, http

TO INSERT values to my table I tried this GET xmlhttprequest object.
Is my syntax correct in the URL? It's not working.

```
document.getElementById('allsubmit').addEventListener('click',sendPost);
  var com = document.getElementById('inputcompany').value;
  var cat = document.getElementById('selectCategory').value;
  var subcat = document.getElementById('selectsubCategory').value;
  var descrip = document.getElementById('textdescription').value;
  var exp = document.getElementById('datepicker').value;

  function sendPost() {
   var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET',"addingthevacancy.php?company='"+com+"'?category='"+cat+"'?subcategory='"+subcat+"'?description='"+descrip+"'?expdate='"+exp,true);

xhr.onprogress = function() {
      //
}

xhr.onload = function() {
    console.log("Processed..."+xhr.readystate);
    console.log(this.responseText);
}

xhr.send();
}
```

I don't know what's wrong here.

Comment: Define "it's not working": Please see the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page.

Comment: When you want to pass in multiple get params, you'll want to format it like so: ```url?company=''&category=''```

Comment: Parameters in a URL *start* with the `?` but each parameter should be separated from the next with `&`, not `?`.

Comment: You should also use `encodeURIComponent()` to encode the parameters properly, in case they contain characters that have special meaning in URLs.

Comment: It's also recommended that you use `POST` rather than `GET` when making changes. `GET` should just be used for retrieval.

Comment: The values were not submitted to the DB. And the same GET values showed as undefined in console. Dave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several issues:

1. Parameters must be separated with `&`, not `?`.
2. URL parameters don't need quotes around them.
3. Parameters should be encoded using `encodeURIComponent()`.
4. You need to get the values of the input inside the `sendPost()` function; your code is setting the variables when the page first loads, not when the user submits.
5. If the button is a submit button, you need to call `e.preventDefault()` to override the default submission.

Using `GET` for requests that make changes on the server is generally not recommended, `POST` should normally be used for these types of requests. Browsers cache `GET` requests, so if you really need to do this, you should add a cache-buster parameter (an extra, unused parameter containing a random string or timestamp that changes each time, just to prevent the URL from matching a cached URL).

```js
document.getElementById('allsubmit').addEventListener('click', sendPost);

function sendPost(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var com = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('inputcompany').value);
  var cat = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('selectCategory').value);
  var subcat = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('selectsubCategory').value);
  var descrip = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('textdescription').value);
  var exp = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('datepicker').value);

  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('GET', "addingthevacancy.php?company=" + com + "&category='" + cat + "&subcategory=" + subcat + "&description=" + descrip + "&expdate=" + exp, true);

  xhr.onprogress = function() {
    //
  }

  xhr.onload = function() {
    console.log("Processed..." + xhr.readystate);
    console.log(this.responseText);
  }

  xhr.send();
}
```